# How to read large files with MappedByteBuffer?

Tags: java, java-io, mappedbytebuffer

I want to read a 30GB file using `MappedByteBuffer`.

```
try (FileChannel sourceChannel = new RandomAccessFile("sample.csv", "r").getChannel()) {
    MappedByteBuffer buf = sourceChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sourceChannel.size());
}
```

Problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:941)
```

What could I do here?

Comment: Not try to memory map files larger than 2GB.

Comment: So can I memory-map the files partially and repeat? My goal is to perform a bytewise copy of the file, but I want to evaluate the content and remove some parts conditionally. Preferably by not having to read each line fully as `String`,  as any string line will have to be converted back into bytes during writing...

Comment: You're trying to solve your earlier problem, but this tool won't help you. You're not doing random access, you're doing ETL. The fastest way to do it is with `BufferedReader/BufferedWriter`.